# Intuition for directional derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Given some function $ z=f(x,y) $, the directional derivative can be used to calculate the rate of change of $ z $ in the direction of some unit vector $ \vec{u} = <a,b> $. The directional derivative for z can then be defined as

$$ D_{\vec{u}}f(x,y) = \lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+ah, y+bh)-f(x, y)}{h} \tag{1} $$

Intuitively, this definition makes sense. By this definition, however, I wouldn't think that $ \vec{u} $ would need to be a unit vector. I feel like $ x + ah $ and $ y + bh $ will become infinitely small regardless of the length of $ \vec{u} $. Is this indeed the case?

Accepting definition $ (1) $, the following equivalent equation makes less sense to me:

$$ D_{\vec{u}}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}a + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}b \tag{2} $$

I've seen a proof of this in which you can go from definition $ (1) $ to equation $ (2) $ via the chain rule. I can fully accept the proof, but I feel like there is something to be said about the actual form of equation $ (2) $. Is there some geometric significance concerning $ (2) $? I feel like the fact that $ \vec{u} $ has to be a unit vector may come into play.

Comment: You're right, $\vec{t}$ need not be a unit vector in order for eq.(1) to make sense. Some authors define directional derivatives with unit vectors, some (probably most) do not. You might read this wikipedia page for a brief sketch of the differences between these two definitions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative

Answer (score 1):

Defining the directional derivative with a unit vector makes no difference, because the directional derivative is homogeneous.
$$
D_{\alpha \vec u} f = \alpha D_{\vec u} f
$$
So choosing to define the directional derivative with unit vectors doesn't make us lose any expressive power thanks to homogeneity. The proof of homogeneity falls almost immediately in your lap if the definition of directional derivative does not require that the direction vector have unit length. Otherwise, it's a straightforward consequence of scalar multiplication.

Comment: It seems that there is a distinction between derivative and differential. If using unit vector, I can understand that $D_{\vec u}f$ is a derivative, because differentials of $f$ can be obtained by multiply derivative with distance (differentials in variables). Now $\vec u$ is not a unit vector, so $D_{\vec u}f$ is more like a differential than a derivative...but it's called directional derivative. So I am confused. Can you please give some hints here? Many thanks!